# MySQL 5.1 relational query from 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Firstly, I'd like to apologise for asking this. I am obviously missing something fundamental here so any help is appreciated.

I have searched the web and my head hurts.

I have 2 tables in my football webapp

```
players
    player_id int(5) primary key
    fullname varchar(30);

squad
    fixture_id int(5) **primary key**
    player1 int(5)
    player2 int(5)
    player3 int(5)
    player4 int(5)
    player5 int(5)
    ...
    ...
    ...
    player11 int(5)
```

The columns in **squad** are populated with the p_id of each player.

Is there a way of selecting all 11 columns from squad but populating them with the fullname column that corresponds to the p_id.

I suppose a basic query might be:

```
SELECT p.fullname 
FROM players p, squad s 
WHERE p.player_id = s.player1
AND s.fixture_id = 533
```

But this only returns for player 1 and I'd like to see all 11 players returned in a single query.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Not easily with this table structure, can you change it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be difficult with a denormalized `squad` table like you have here: you'd need do either do 11 `JOIN`s or do some funky pivoting.  What you might try instead is to normalize your `squad` table as such:

```
squad
    fixture_id int(5)
    player_id int(5)
    player_position int(5)
```

Now, instead of having one row represent a squad, you would have 11 (one for each player; `player_position` would be an integer representing the player's place on the squad).  A query to list the full names of all players on a squad would then look like this:

```
SELECT s.fixture_id AS Squad, s.player_position AS Position, p.fullname AS Player
FROM squad AS s
    INNER JOIN players AS p ON
        s.player_id = p.player_id
WHERE s.fixture_id = 533
ORDER BY player_position
```

The output of this query would look something like:

```
Squad | Position | Player
533   | 1        | Billy Bob
533   | 2        | Rilly Rob
533   | 3        | Filly Fob
...
```

The advantage of this normalized design is that data storage and retrieval becomes simpler, you can easily take advantage of relational integrity constraints between the `player` and `squad` tables, and you can very easily change the size of your squads if need be.  The tradeoff is that you will need to do a bit more work to display the data in the denormalized/tabular form, and you will also need to manage the assignment of the `player_position` properly.

Comment: Thank you Gerf. Would you believe I had this table design in the first place but opted for something different to try out getting all of the data for a single fixture into a single row.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    select p.fullname From players p ,squad d 
    where p.id IN (d.player1,d.player2, ....,player11)
    and d.fixture_id=1
```

Comment: Thanks Hardik, I tried this code out and it isn't quite what I was after but still very useful. I am going to go with Gerf's suggestion above and normalize my tables. Thanks again